# Verifiable Base Point generation via NIST SP 800-186 method

Tags: elliptic-curves, nist

I'm looking at D.3.2 Verifiably Random Base Points of [NIST SP 800-186](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-186-draft.pdf). Looks like step 5 is there to ensure that $hashlen > bitLen(q)+1$ and (potentially) discard big $e$, so $t$ is distributed properly. However, the generation method won't work in if $hashlen < bitLen(q)$ (say SHA256 and Curve448). Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: The step only checks that the division is not the same. You may choose a large hash like SHA-512.

Comment: @kelalaka, yes but when hashlen is smaller than qbitLen, it's an infinite loop, no? With a bigger hashlen there is no problem, but I wonder how to make it work with a smaller one